# No gridlines displayed for y3axis in jqPlot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

Please have a look at this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mumtaz/B8kfS/).

```
 series: [{
        yaxis: 'yaxis',
        tickOptions: {
            showGridline: true
        }
    }, {
        yaxis: 'y3axis',
        tickOptions: {
            showGridline: true
        }
    }, {
        yaxis: 'yaxis',
        tickOptions: {
            showGridline: true
        }
    }]
```

There are no gridlines against y3axis' ticks.

And also [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mumtaz/6vc2u/),

```
series: [{
        yaxis: 'y3axis',           
        tickOptions: {
            showGridline: true
        }
    }, {
        yaxis: 'y3axis',
        tickOptions: {
            showGridline: true
        }
    }, {
        yaxis: 'y3axis',
        tickOptions: {
            showGridline: true
        }
    }]
```

There are no gridlines at all  if all the series are plotted against y3axis. The same is true for y4axis.

Can someone help me with how I can make the gridlines appear for y3axis as well?

Comment: your jsfiddle links are not working

Comment: I am sorry for my stupidity. Now the links should be working.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this issue because you are using the 'y3axis' before you have used 'y2axis'. In your 1st jsFiddle change 'y3axis' to 'y2axis' (i.e. yaxis: 'y2axis') and you will then see all the grid lines. Similarly, if you change 'y3axis' to 'yaxis' in your second jsFiddle you will again see all the gridlines.

As the y-values vary greatly between you data sets, why not render your graph so all three y-axes are clearly discernable on screen as follows? :

[image]

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/brEAy/) for how I did this.

The jqPlot code used to render this chart is:

```
      var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1, line2, line3], {
        title:'Plot with 3 Y-Axes', 
        series:[
            {},
            {yaxis:'y2axis'}, 
            {yaxis:'y3axis'}
        ], 
        axesDefaults:{useSeriesColor: true}, 
        axes:{
            xaxis:{min:0, max:7, numberTicks: 8}, 
            yaxis:{min:0, max:60, label: 'line1'},  
            y2axis:{
                min:2000, 
                max:70000,
                tickOptions: { showGridline: false }, label: 'line2'
            }, 
            y3axis:{ label: 'line3'}
        },
        highlighter: {
            show: true,
            sizeAdjust: 1
        }
    });
```

Also not how I've used the highlighter option so it's easy to see the x and y values for a point when a user hovers over a plotted point.

See [here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/zooming.php) for another approach you could take which would make use of jqPlots zoom facility.

Comment: So if I have only 1 series plotted against the y3axis like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/Mumtaz/qH5wX/) why the gridlines are still not displayed? This time the values in yaxis do not vary significantly.

Comment: If you only have one series, then really you should not use 'y3axis' for the y-axis, you should instead use 'yaxis'. If you change your fiddle to use "yaxis: 'yaxis'", then the x and y grid lines are displayed.

Comment: yes, I know. But I have an application where I have 4 radio buttons corresponding to 4 y-axes(yaxis,y2axis,y3axis,y4axis). And a series will be plotted against the selected yaxis. I am not able to understand why jqplot does not display gridlines for y3axis/y4axis.